# How to find change in column from table?

Tags: sql

```
ID      PNUM    CUR    DTDATE    
---------------------------------------------
1       112233  001  31.01.2012
2       112233  001  31.03.2012
3       112233  001  30.04.2012
4       112233  058  31.05.2012
5       112244  001  31.01.2012
6       112244  398  31.03.2012
```

I have this table of records and I want to find out were there any change
in column CUR for each PNUM throug all the time? How to write an SQL statements for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below Query. Also always mention the RDMS.

```
select PNUM,count(distinct CUR) changecount
from table
group by PNUM
having count(distinct CUR)>1
```

Comment: @noors Consider it as answer if it helped you